# SQL TABLE naming. persons vs. people

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm looking to create a new TABLE in my database but ran into a naming conundrum. I initially wanted to create the table as **people**

But then I got to thinking... should I name the table **people** or **persons**

```
TABLE CREATE persons(name string, age integer)
or
TABLE CREATE people(name string, age integer)
```

Comment: Either way, the table should be pluralized.

But either one, will do.

Comment: Why *should* the name be pluralized? There is no rule for this. This is all about coding conventions which are (to a certain extent) a matter of taste

Comment: I'm in a ruby on rails programming bootcamp. And in the context of ruby on rails, we were told it is important to name all your tables plural. That's why I thought it should be plural.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The words people and persons can both be used as the plural of person,People is by far the more common of the two words and is used in most ordinary contexts: "a group of people"; "there were only about ten people"

if you are going to have particular person's detail [attributes of individuals ] as `name`, `age`... then I think you should go with "`persons`'

```
TABLE CREATE persons(name string, age integer)
```

if you would have fields in the table like `People_count` ,`Avg_Age` , `Totalvote` etc , then you should have choose table name "`People`"

Comment: Because the table is normalized there is no difference between the persons, they are part of one collective group.  *People* would be correct. http://www.worldwidewords.org/articles/people.htm

Comment: The confusion about "Persons vs People" is yet another argument for using singular, rather than plural.  The table name should be "Person".

Answer (score 6):

This is debated and often considered a matter of opinion, however I recommend always using singular. Your table name should be 'Person'.

- A table should be named the 'object' of what it contains. Plural is 'redundant', the table may always have 0, 1 or more items in it, using a singular reference standardises this across the board.
- You can think of a table as an object - a 'container' of something. For example if you have a Box of Mushrooms, then it is a 'MushroomBox', it doesn't make sense to call it a 'MushroomBoxes'. Whether it has 0, 1, or many mushrooms in it, it's always a 'MushroomBox'.
- Plural names can have more irregularities and complexities such as "ies", "es" vs "s" or words such as "Status" and "Mice" vs "Mouse" etc. Singular is simpler, easier and more consistent.
- If you have related tables, a singular naming convention carries over better. Say you have one table 'Student' and another Table 'Room'. You could potentially have a 'StudentRoom' table. But the name 'StudentsRoom' or 'StudentsRooms' is confusing.
- When you refer to a column within a table, singular makes sense. Take the following example: SELECT * FROM Person WHERE Person.FirstName = 'John' makes more sense than SELECT * FROM Persons where Persons.Firstname = 'John' because you are talking about "a row", or "a person".
- Singular uses less characters :)

Comment: Disagree with some of the points, especially the *StudentsRooms*.  The combination of pluralization can be used as a device for naming bridge tables.  For instance, *StudentRooms* suggests one to many relationship (1 student_id with multiple room_ids), *StudentsRooms* suggests multiple student_ids can be assigned to multiple rooms.  *Students* by itself would be a collection of students and *Rooms* by itself a collection of rooms.

I also don't see how pluralizing is any less redundant than making it singular, as you said it can be 0, 1, or more.

Comment: Regarding your MushroomBox, you've created a new adjective to refer to one collection, which is what the table is, rather than hinting at the individuals.  *MushroomBoxes* doesn't make sense because the table isn't referring to the many boxes, *MushroomsBox* would make more sense to refer to the collective, still grammatically inferior to *Box of Mushrooms*.  If you have a table of students for a school, you don't create a new descriptor/modifier, it isn't *StudentSchools*; it's *Students* or *SchoolStudents* -- *Box of Mushrooms* and *Mushroom Box* are equivalent, *MushroomBoxes* is not.

Comment: I prefer this naming convention too. It allows you to infer that a table named `Widget` contains one Widget per row, and the table called `Widgets` contains multiple Widgets per row. If you pluralise your table names then you lose that flexibility. My only reservation is that this naming convention is uncommon in the wild and adhering to conventions is generally a good thing.

Comment: Those of us who have been around since oracle enterprise days will be used to singular table names as a standard.

Answer (score 3):

The correct plural of *person* when talking about a collective group is *people*; unless talking in legal terms, which generally refers to first, second, and third persons or specifying individuals.  (See here: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/46294/correct-usage-of-persons-vs-people for more)

Because they are in the same table, they follow a normalized form, which suggests they are a collective group, thus use *people*.

This gets into a larger question about nomenclature, which the general rule is to be consistent.  When it comes to database schemas, I generally pluralized the table names and then use a singular alias in the SQL — it's more work, but easier to read, for instance:

```
SELECT person.first_name, person.last_name
FROM   people person
WHERE  person.age > 18
```